# angularjs infdig error when change state on ui-router(with video)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

**New Edit:** *the authservice that checks the login*:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MainApp.login.services', [])
    .factory('authService', ['AUTH_ENDPOINT', 'LOGOUT_ENDPOINT', '$http', '$cookieStore', function (AUTH_ENDPOINT, LOGOUT_ENDPOINT, $http, $cookieStore) {
        var auth = {};
        auth.login = function (username, password) {
            return $http.post(AUTH_ENDPOINT, {username: username, password: password})
                .then(function (response, status) {
                    auth.user = response.data;
                    $cookieStore.put('user', auth.user);
                    return auth.user;
                });
        };
        auth.logout = function () {
            return $http.post(LOGOUT_ENDPOINT).then(function (response) {
                auth.user = undefined;
                $cookieStore.remove('user');
                $cookieStore.remove('event');
            });
        };
        return auth;
    }])
    .value('AUTH_ENDPOINT', 'http://www.mydomain.gr/assets/modules/login/dal/login.php')
    .value('LOGOUT_ENDPOINT', 'http://www.mydomain.gr/assets/modules/login/dal/logout.php');
```

Updated:
Unfortunatelly this is a part of a whole web-application , so i cant upload it on jsfiddle. I made a youtube video where i show exactly the error while i debug the application. From minute 1:30 starts the problem.Feel free to examine the video
below is the **app.js** of my angular application.

*Could the $watch(es) that i have into the templates ,create the error?*

**Youtube, after 1:30 starts the error** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Cc2--BkdQ4&feature=youtu.be

When first load the site , the login screen loads and asks for the credentials.

If the user login it redirects to the part4 page(from inside the login controller) , so far so good!

The problem is whenever i open a new tab on the browser , try to load the website:

1. It should see that the user is already loged in and redirect him on the part4 page.
2. instead of this , as i see on the debug of the browser , it goes to the resolve:login
3. Then it goes up inside `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',` and to the `go.state(part4)`
4. Then it goes to the resolve of part4 and then it goes to the resolve of the login and again to the $statechangeerror function

5.And finally i get the error :`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D`
but the strange is that it finally redirects to the part4 page, but with that error!!

Can anyone help me please.

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MainApp', ['mApp',
    'MainApp.loginModule',
    'MainApp.part4Module',
    'MainApp.part5Module',
    'MainApp.eventModule',
    'ui.router', 'ui.router.tabs', 'ngCookies']);

angular.module('MainApp')
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$cookieStore', 'authService', function ($rootScope, $state, $cookieStore, authService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            if (error.unAuthorized) {
                $state.go('login');
            }
            else if (error.authorized) {
                $state.go('part4');
            }
        });

        authService.user = $cookieStore.get('user');
    }])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) { //$stateProvider & $urlRouterProvider are from ui.router module
        $stateProvider
            .state('floorplan', {
                url: '/floorplan/:activeEventId/:activeHallId/:activeHallVariant',
                controller: 'ParticipantsCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/assets/modules/part1/part1.html',
                resolve: {
                    user: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
                        return authService.user || $q.reject({unAuthorized: true});
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('event', {
                url: '/event/:activeEventId',
                templateUrl: 'assets/modules/event/eventPartial.html',
                controller: 'eventctrl',
                resolve: {
                    user: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
                        return authService.user || $q.reject({unAuthorized: true});
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('part4', {
                url: '/part4',
                resolve: {
                    user: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
                        return authService.user || $q.reject({unAuthorized: true});
                    }]
                },
                controller: 'part4ctrl',
                templateUrl: '/assets/modules/part4/part4Partial.html'
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/assets/modules/login/login.html',
                resolve: {
                    user: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
                        if (authService.user) {   
                         return $q.reject({authorized: true});
                        }
                    }]
                }
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
    });
```

[image]

**I uploaded a video on youtube , describing and showing the error:**
youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Cc2--BkdQ4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your `app.js`. I'm fairly sure it should be `app.run...` not `angular.module('MainApp').run`

Comment: @LJ.Wizard using `angular.module('MainApp')` is better practice. Doesn't depend on setting a global variable

Comment: Hard to help without knowing how authorization works

Comment: @charlietfl I see. Thanks.

Comment: You're getting yourself into an infinite loop.. could you get an `error.authorized` when you get routed to the part4 state?

Comment: Is `authService` a `$resource` object? Or does it make `$http` calls? It would be helpful to see how it works.

Comment: i am working on a video right now, i will upload it into the day. Thanks

Comment: I uploaded a debugging video on youtube with the error.

Comment: @TheoItzaris, can you also provide sample [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview), where we can reproduce it?

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is a part of a whole web-application , so i cant upload it on jsfiddle. I made a youtube video where i show exactly the error while i debug the application. From minute 1:30 starts the problem.Feel free to examine the video.

Comment: did you tryed out my answer or do you need some code as example ? I'm pretty sure i can resolve it ince i already had some race problem with $state and getting the current connected user :)

Comment: i didnt try your answer because it is a little complilcated for me.Do you need a user to login?

Comment: Keep everything as is and add $stateChangeStart as suggested. Once it works remove others. It will resolve. It works for me. You are getting into a code loop basically

Comment: `Could the $watch(es) that i have into the templates ,create the error?` Yes, it can if some unknown bug is there. But your debugging shows different - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it does not go into any controller , but i cant understand what creates the error. I think I am going to fill all the js files with breakpoints.

Comment: the error is event, promise, and change related. i have had such errors generally with the first attempt of click. statechangeerror too many times seems to be creating the issue. one reason why i prefer statechangestart than statechangeerror. these are eventlisteners and when used inside run will be active across app lifecycle until destroyed manually. do try the logic inverted with statechangestart and for specific route customization use resolve. good to know the issue was resolved.

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below.

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind that you deleted all my answer and i have to write it again from the start. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Everything seems ok.

After many hours and many breakpoints i realized that the problem was not caused by any `$watch()`, i have many `$watch` on my controllers.

It is just a state problem, as you can see on my question , i didnt have **'/'** state, and that caused the infinite loop ,because:

1. when i delete the extension part of the url , i have : www.mydomain.com/ , then the `$stateProvider` searches my available **'states'** but couldnt find '/' state, so it redirects to 'login' state.
2. Into 'login' state i check if user==true and reject error.
3. Then , $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError'){..} executes and i call state.go('part4') , it resolves state 'part4' and again it goes to state 'login' resolve ,and again the same  until the maximum number of allowed iterations of the $digest cycle reached.

### How i solved it

I dont know if it is the best way but i added a '/' state on app.js, and it works as expected:

```
.state('/', {
                url: '/',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/assets/modules/login/login.html',
                resolve: {
                    user: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
                        if (authService.user) {
                            return $q.reject({authorized: true, user: authService.user});
                        }
                    }]
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the state is resolved first because you inject $state in your app.run.

Which lead to try to resolve the part4 state's resolve with undefined user, then the event is thrown and will be resolved on the next digest cycle, so the use is initialized before you get redirecit to login page, which will redirect you to part4.

Try to separate in two angular.run, the 1st that will run the init of the authService without injectingt $state. The 2nd that will inject the $state to init the$stateCHangeError listener (just defining the 1st one before the 2nd one).

If it's not enough : split your module : the one containing the authService in a module 'A' with the dedicated angular.module('A').run, the 2nd in a module 'B' with a dependency toward 'A' with the angular.module('B').run for the $stateChangeError

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this inverted?

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$cookieStore', 'authService', function ($rootScope, $state, $cookieStore, authService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (...) {
    authService.user = $cookieStore.get('user');
                if (authService.user) {
                    $state.go('part4');
                }
                else if (!authService.user) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            });
}
```

This will skip the to and fro to the $q within your resolve in each route's declaration. Second, this will also resolve you/r checking user all the time within resolve of each route. In .config() set `authService.user = $cookieStore.get('user');` somewhere. Should resolve your issue.

Comment: it's $stateChangeError not $stateChangeStart, otherwise he's navigation will have some problem to go on others page than part4 and login :P

Comment: yes, i want @theo-itzaris to approach the authentication and url change using `$stateChangeStart` and initializing the `authService.user = $cookieStore.get('user');` in the config. i am approaching the other way round. $q is unnecessary here.